# How to install .apk file from local storage programmatically in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to implement this functionality;
**

> A Button when pressed will install .apk file from local storage with the following path.

**

```
String _apkFilePath = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/filename.apk';
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This package may help you. [OpenFile](https://pub.dev/packages/open_file)

```
OpenFile.open("..apk_file_path_here"); // to launch an apk_installer in the device
```

Comment: Glad it helped. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Due to the library dependency issue, **open_file** is not workable for me

I switch to **[open_filex](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex)**

Add permission to android file **/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DELETE_PACKAGES" />
```

Open the APK file

```
Future<void> openAPK() async {
  final result = await OpenFilex.open("/storage/emulated/0/Download/filename.apk");
}
```

*Note: enable "Install unknown apps" might required*

Comment: open_file and open_filex doesn't work, even after add the packages to the pubspec they are missing